# Como ajustar a margem do topo do PDF para o seguinte problema em html2pdf.js?

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf, html2pdf-js

[Esta é a principal referência](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html)

A ideia era que a imagem ficasse por trás, porém a lib é meio limitada para isso, e o texto acabou ficando por cima:

Aqui tem um exemplo, veja que apesar da imagem ser transparente, ela está indo para cima do texto, a imagem está na linha 38 do fiddle, eu não consegui colocar nenhuma imagem no jsfiddle, porque o CORS bloqueia imagens externas, por isso coloquei o logo do fiddle:
[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/us3d52p9/)

[Aqui um exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/2j7xpodL/) com a imagem chapada.

[jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf)

[Lib que estou utilizando baseada no jsPDF](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js)

> **Obs:** Estou utilizando esta lib porque infelizmente o método `.fromHTML()` do jsPDF não alinha os textos para a direita, somente centralizado e à esquerda, por conta disso, tive que pegar uma lib que convertia o conteúdo em html2canvas primeiro para depois transformá-lo em jsPDF e depois gerar o pdf, o problema é que a lib primeiro processa o conteúdo em HTML, e depois, quando está pronto, ele permite jogar elementos no footer / header, entretanto, o meu PDF precisa ter na primeira página, uma imagem de fundo e uma legenda no cabeçalho, a legenda OK, o problema é que a imagem ficou por cima do texto.

Resolvi o problema com CSS, mas tive um problema com a margem da segunda página:

**Código que gera o PDF:**

```
var printPDF = function(name) {

    var element = '<style type="text/css">.legend{border: 1px solid #81c02e;font-size: 10px; line-height: 2em; display: block;  width: 100%;} .box-info-aluno p { line-height: 15px} p strong.ql-font-courier {font-family:courier}</style><style type="text/css">body { margin: 0 30px 30px; font-family: helvetica, "arial", sans-serif; color: #000000} p {font-family: helvetica, "arial", sans-serif} .ql-editor {font-size: 12pt; line-height: 2em; color:#000000} .ql-editor p {font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif; line-height: 2em; color:#000000} .ql-editor p g {font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.3em} .ql-font-times { font-family: "times";} .ql-font-courier { font-family: "courier";} .legend .box-info-aluno {padding: 8px; width: 100%} img { max-width: 520px; padding-top: 10px padding-bottom: 10px}</style><div class="ql-editor" data-gramm="false" data-gram_editor="false" contenteditable="false"><p class="" style="text-align:center;  line-height: 2em"><strong class="gr_" style="font-size: 24pt;"><g class="gr_">TÍTULO DA MATÉRIA</g></strong></p><p class="ql-align-right"><strong class="gr_" style="font-size: 24pt;"><g class="gr_">fdsafaf</g></strong></p><p><div class="img-box">HTML de exemplo</div></p></div>';

    var container = document.createElement('div');

  var callbackImgFundo = '/img/logo.png';
                    container.setAttribute('class', 'container-print-box');
                    container.innerHTML = element;

                    var ed = container.querySelector('.ql-editor');

                    container.removeChild(ed);

                    var container_print = document.createElement('div')
                    container_print.setAttribute('class', 'container-print');
                    var css = document.createElement('style');
                    css.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
                    css.innerHTML = '.container-print {background: #fff url("'+callbackImgFundo+'") center top no-repeat; background-size: contain}.legend{border: 1px solid #81c02e;font-size: 10px; line-height: 2em; display: block;  width: 100%;} .ql-editor {margin: 0 50px 50px 50px!important; padding-top: 90px;}'
                    container_print.appendChild(css)
                    container_print.appendChild(ed);

                    container.appendChild(container_print);

                    element = container;




 var opt = {
                    margin:       [0, 0, 0, 0], //top, left, buttom, right
                    filename:    name + '.pdf',
                    image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
                    html2canvas:  { dpi: 192, scale: 2, letterRendering: true},
                    jsPDF:        { unit: 'pt', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait'},
                    pageBreak: { mode: 'avoid-all'}
                    };


var worker = html2pdf()
    .set(opt)
    .from(element)
    .toPdf()
    .get('pdf')
    .then(function(doc) {


        var totalPages = doc.internal.getNumberOfPages();


        for(var i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++ ) {   

            if (i == 1) {
                doc.setPage(i);

                //doc.addImage('/img/logo.png', 'PNG', 0, 0, 600, 850);
                 //  doc.setPage(i);
                doc.setFontType("bold");
                doc.text(330, 40, 'Matéria: ');
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                doc.text(380, 40,  'No onno nono nononono');

                doc.setFontType("bold");
                doc.text(330, 60, 'Atividade: ');
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                doc.text(390, 60, 'Nonnono onno nonono');
                doc.setFontSize(12);
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                 doc.setPage(i);

                console.log(doc.internal)

            } else {
                doc.setpage(i);
                /* QUAL MÉTODO EXISTE PARA EU SETAR 
                   A MARGEM QUANDO NÃO FOR A PRIMEIRA PÁGINA????
                 */
            }
        }



    })

    .save();
}
```

O método que adiciona a imagem e esse: 
`.addImage()`

[Esta é a única maneira](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/dv5mwxbk/) que eu consegui fazer, porém preciso agora poder melhorar a margem da segunda página, ela está cortando no topo, como poderia ajustar isso no callback?

A mesma dúvida, um caso similar numa [versão do stack overflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57752081/how-to-add-padding-after-page-break-using-html2pdf)

Comment: Certo, mas o seu `if()` já não está configurado para fazer com que a primeira pagina receba a imagem?

Comment: Exatamente, @Azzi, o `if()` configura para que receba a imagem somente na primeira página, mas ela está ficando por cima do texto, eu queria esta imagem por trás do texto..

Comment: Se você colocar `float` no texto e alinhar não vai ficar bom?

Comment: @Azzi, não entendi, em que isso mudaria? Talvez z-index, mas é uma regra de PDF, acho que não muda nada.

Comment: @IvanFerrer Pelo q vi a biblioteca que você esta usando usa, por trás o jsPdf, e o addImage dele não possui opção de z-Index para indicar se quer colocar na frente ou por trás do texto, mais informações [neste link](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-addImage.html)

Comment: Uma outra opção seria adicionar ao HTML a imagem com zIndex, com posições fixas baseadas no tamanho da página antes de gerar o Pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infelizmente eu não consegui encontrar nenhuma solução de editar a margem depois de quebrar a página, mas resolvi o problema mantendo a margem padrão para: `[30, 0, 30, 0]`. A imagem de fundo, no caso tem um box onde é o espaço da legenda do trabalho com dados do autor.

Eu fiz o ajuste da imagem de fundo no CSS, meu código ficou assim:

```
var printPDF = function(name) {

    var element = '<style type="text/css">.legend{border: 1px solid #81c02e;font-size: 10px; line-height: 2em; display: block;  width: 100%;} .box-info-aluno p { line-height: 15px} p strong.ql-font-courier {font-family:courier}</style><style type="text/css">body { margin: 0 30px 30px; font-family: helvetica, "arial", sans-serif; color: #000000} p {font-family: helvetica, "arial", sans-serif} .ql-editor {font-size: 12pt; line-height: 2em; color:#000000} .ql-editor p {font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif; line-height: 2em; color:#000000} .ql-editor p g {font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.3em} .ql-font-times { font-family: "times";} .ql-font-courier { font-family: "courier";} .legend .box-info-aluno {padding: 8px; width: 100%} img { max-width: 520px; padding-top: 10px padding-bottom: 10px}</style><div class="ql-editor" data-gramm="false" data-gram_editor="false" contenteditable="false"><p class="" style="text-align:center;  line-height: 2em"><strong class="gr_" style="font-size: 24pt;"><g class="gr_">TÍTULO DA MATÉRIA</g></strong></p><p class="ql-align-right"><strong class="gr_" style="font-size: 24pt;"><g class="gr_">fdsafaf</g></strong></p><p><div class="img-box">HTML de exemplo</div></p></div>';

    //imagem do fundo
    var callbackImgFundo = '/img/logo.png'; 
    var container = document.createElement('div'); 
    var opt = {
               margin:       [30, 0, 30, 0], //top, left, buttom, right
               filename:    doc_name,
               image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
               html2canvas:  { dpi: 192, scale: 2, letterRendering: true},
               jsPDF:        { unit: 'pt', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait'},
               pageBreak: { mode: 'legacy'},
               compressPDF: true
              };
    var container = document.createElement('div');
        container.setAttribute('class', 'container-print-box');
        container.innerHTML = extra_1;
    var ed = container.querySelector('.ql-editor');
             container.removeChild(ed);
    var container_print = document.createElement('div')
        container_print.setAttribute('class', 'container-print');
    var css = document.createElement('style');
        css.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
        //AJUSTEI O CSS DA IMAGEM DE FUNDO, DESCENDO UM POUCO A CAIXA DAS LEGENDAS
        css.innerHTML = '.container-print {background: #fff url("'+callbackImgFundo+'") center -5px no-repeat; background-size: 800px 1120px;} .ql-editor {margin: -20px 50px 50px 50px!important; padding-top: 140px;}';
        container_print.appendChild(css)
        container_print.appendChild(ed);
        container.appendChild(container_print);
        extra_1 = container;  
        var worker = html2pdf();
            worker.set(opt)
                  .from(extra_1)
                  .toPdf()
                  .get('pdf')
                  .then(function (doc) {
                     var totalPages = doc.internal.getNumberOfPages();
                     for (var i=1; i<=totalPages; i++) {
                         if (i == 1) {
                             doc.setPage(1);
                             //AJUSTEI A MARGEM DESCENDO UM POUCO O TEXTO PARA ENCAIXAR NA IMAGEM DE FUNDO DAS LEGENDAS
                             var _top_margin = 10;
                             doc.setFontType("bold");
                             doc.text(330, 40+_top_margin, 'Matéria: ');
                             doc.setFontType("normal");
                             doc.text(380, 40+_top_margin,  'No onno nono nononono');
                             doc.setFontType("bold");
                             doc.text(330, 60+_top_margin, 'Atividade: ');
                             doc.setFontType("normal");
                             doc.text(390, 60+_top_margin, 'Nonnono onno nonono');
                             doc.setFontSize(12);
                             doc.setFontType("normal");
                          } else {
                             doc.setPage(i);
                          }
                       }
                    }).save();
}
```